# Confusion in id parameter in django

Tags: django

I was making an E Commerce website and added various products in it. Now for making a cart i made a add to cart button. And in HTML i assigned an id to this button. The id was pr{{product.id}}. I have not made buttons individually for every item. There is a for loop running which creates buttons. Now My doubt is that i have not assigned any field id in the models class. But still this code is running and when i printed the id's on the console i realised that it prints like pr32, pr33, pr34 ie in a sequential manner. So is there any product.id field predefined in django??

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is that I have not assigned any field `id` in the models class.

You *don't need to*. If you do not add a primary key yourself, Django will add a field with the name `id` that is an `AutoField`. This is [documented in the *Automatic primary key fields* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> By **default, Django gives each model the following field**:
>
> ```
> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
> ```
>
> This is an auto-incrementing primary key.
>
> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify
>   `primary_key=True` on *one* of your fields. If Django sees you’ve
>   explicitly set `Field.primary_key`, it won’t add the automatic id
>   column.
>
> Each model requires **exactly one field** to have `primary_key=True`
>   (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

So to answer your question:

> So is there any `product.id` field predefined in django?

**Yes**, if you did *not* specify a field with `primary_key=True` yourself.